# Javascript Change function not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

Change function does not work on mobile but on desktop it works perfectly. jQuery is not option here. I have this piece of code:

```js
const boxWrapper = document.getElementById("top-menu");
const box = document.createElement("li");
box.innerHTML = '<select id="menjajjezik"><option id="hr">HR</option><option id="eng" selected>ENG</option></select>';

boxWrapper.appendChild(box);

var el_option = document.getElementById("menjajjezik");
el_option.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.selectedIndex == 1) {
    location.href = 'https://link1.com/';
  } else {
    location.href = 'https://link2.com/';
  }
}, false);
```

Is it problem that previously I created and append this element? It should change to other link when I change value in select box, but it does not work.

Comment: Not all html elements emit a change event, it's seeams to me that it's an option element, if it's the case you need to listen on the select not the option

Comment: It's impossible to suggest anything useful without its counterpart -- HTML.

Comment: If the element with `id="menjajjezik"` is an `option` element (as your variable name `el_option` suggests it is), beware that not all browsers support `change` events on `option` elements. Use the event on the `select` instead.

Comment: "Is it problem that previusly I created and append this element?"  Do you mean that your document has two select elements with the same ID?

Comment: @Lk77  It is confusingly named, but el_option is where the eventlistener is attached, and is clearly the SELECT element:  menjajjezik   (if all is working correctly...)